# how to define static fields for type parameter in java generics

Tags: java, oop, generics, interface, static

I want to define a time interface like that:

```
public interface TimeInterface<T>
{
    static T ZERO;
    static T INFINITY;
    // some other methods...
}
```

Is this possible, or how to do that to avoid errors?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) directly:

> ##### Cannot Declare Static Fields Whose Types are Type Parameters
>
> A class's static field is a class-level variable shared by all non-static objects of the class. Hence, static fields of type parameters are not allowed. Consider the following class:
>
> ```java
> public class MobileDevice<T> {
>     private static T os;
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> If static fields of type parameters were allowed, then the following code would be confused:
>
> ```java
> MobileDevice<Smartphone> phone = new MobileDevice<>();
> MobileDevice<Pager> pager = new MobileDevice<>();
> MobileDevice<TabletPC> pc = new MobileDevice<>();
> ```
>
> Because the static field `os` is shared by `phone`, `pager`, and `pc`, what is the actual type of `os`? It cannot be `Smartphone`, `Pager`, and `TabletPC` at the same time. You cannot, therefore, create static fields of type parameters.

Answer (score 5):

The **only** `static` thing that can contain type-parameters is the `static` method, which must define it's own type-parameters. Something like:

```
static <T> void staticGenericMethod(T param) { .. }
```

In your case, the type-parameter has a class scope, it's instance-bound and has nothing to do with the `static` members of the class.

So, you should *either* remove the `static` keywords for `ZERO` and `INFINITY` *or* introduce `static` methods that return `ZERO` and `INFINITY`. For example:

```
public interface TimeInterface<T> {
    static <X> X getZero() { 
         //implementation
    }
    static <X> X getInfinity() {

    }
}
```

Note that the `X` type-parameters are valid for the corresponding static method only and are not shared across the class.

The problem, however, with this approach is that there's no way to *ensure* that the instance type-parameter (`T`) is the same as the static method's type-parameter (`X`), which may cause serious problems when used incorrectly.

Also note that `static` methods are allowed in interfaces in Java8, so if you're using an order Java version, you should convert the `TimeInterface` to a class.