# Java Generic: Why class variable "static T t" is not allowed?

Tags: java, generics

I understand after type erasure, that the type info is lost, and all instances of generic class are using the same class.

```
public class Test<T> {
    public T a;
    public static T b;
}
```

After type erasure, why don't the compiler just make a raw type like:

```
public class Test {
    public Object a;
    public static Object b;
}
```

But now it is compiler-time error. Any reason behind?

Comment: Because (by definition) a `static` field isn't associated with an *instance*.

Comment: It's by design. I think C# allows you to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263222/how-to-define-static-fields-for-type-parameter-in-java-generics

Comment: This makes sense. If that was allowed, you could `Test<String>.b = "x";` then `Long b = Test<Long>.b;` with no unchecked warnings at all.

Comment: @acdcjunior IMO, the compiler should be designed smart enough caught the `Long b = Test<Long>.b;` during compile time, with error "Object cannot be casted to Long".So other than designer personal preference I don't think  there is a "real" reason.

Comment: Yeah, but since, in reality, `b` is an `Object`, and considering two assignments like `Test<String>.b = 1L;` and `Test<String>.b = "str";`  are present, what should determinate `b`'s actual type? The order of execution? A bit random, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @acdcjunior Indeed in reality I will never write `static T b;`, the reason why I ask here is I was being asked by an "interviewer", who apparently knows nothing about generic(indeed all aspect of programming) but has the power to do candidate screening and, someone prepared a Q&A list for him, so him mindlessly run-thru the list to judge if you are "good". Anyway, thx for the feed back.